# Read a binary file and send over Modbus RTU using Python 3 (how to convert 'str' to an 'int')

Tags: python

I have made a PCB circuit that has a microcontroller (Microchip `PIC18F47K40`) that can program a parallel flash memory (Microchip `SST39SF040`).

The microcontroller communicates to my PC (Windows 10) via `Modbus RTU` over a USB to UART adaptor.

I use five Modbus registers...

`Control, Address0, Address1, Address2, Data`

`Control = read, write, erase`

`Address0,1,2 = Address bus`

`Data = Data bus`

Using Baseblock program I have verified the microcontroller is working fine, and in Python I can send individual commands ok.

My goal is to be able to read in a binary file and send to the microcontroller to program the flash memory chip.

This is the code I have so far: -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import minimalmodbus
instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('COM8', 1)
instrument.serial.baudrate = 9600
instrument.close_port_after_each_call = True

addressCount = 0
with open("rom.bin", "rb") as f:
    while (dataByte := f.read(1)):
        addressBytes = ( (addressCount).to_bytes(3, byteorder='little') )
        addressCount += 1
        instrument.write_register(0, 0x3, 0)
        instrument.write_register(1, addressBytes[0], 0)
        instrument.write_register(2, addressBytes[1], 0)
        instrument.write_register(3, addressBytes[2], 0)
        #instrument.write_register(4, dataByte.hex(), 0)
        print(dataByte.hex())
```

The line that is causing me problems is: -

```
instrument.write_register(4, dataByte.hex(), 0)
```

The error message: -

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
The input value must be numerical. Given: '85'
  File "X:\Code\Python\1-modbus_master_flas_read_write_erase\#4 - numpy.py", line 17, in <module>
    instrument.write_register(4, dataByte.hex(), 0)
```

When I check the type for `dataByte.hex()` it comes back as a `str`...

So, my question, how do I convert the `str` to an `int`?

Comment: So this is a very verbose way of asking your question. For future reference, I'd recommend maybe cutting down the detail. In addition, this is easily googleable and very basic python:

int(str)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `int(dataByte.hex())`

```
databyte = b'101010'
databyte = databyte.hex()
print(type(databyte)) # <class 'str'>
databyte = int(databyte,16)
print(type(databyte)) # <class 'int'>
```

Comment: When I try that on "print( int(dataByte.hex()))" it works on the first 3 bytes in the binary file (85, 56, 20), but fails on the 4th byte which is '0f'. invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0f'

Comment: 0f = 1111 in binary, I tried it changing the above and it works. What is the error?

Comment: Exception has occurred: ValueError
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0f'
  File "X:\Code\Python\1-modbus_master_flas_read_write_erase\#4 - numpy.py", line 18, in <module>
    print( int (dataByte.hex()))

Comment: I updated my answer, forgot to copy add the important ",16": `databyte = int(databyte,16)`